# Trouble parsing array of Longs to bean using JSONObject.toBean

Tags: java, json, javabeans

I'm trying to create beans from JSON using net.sf.json.JSONObject.toBean.  I've gotten past a lot of hurdles, but am a little stuck on this one.

The pertinent part of my bean is:

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private TreeSet<Long> fooSet = new TreeSet<Long>();

    public Long[] getFoo() {
        return fooSet.toArray(new Long[0]);
    }

    public void setFoo(Long[] fooArray) {
        for(Long foo: fooArray)
            this.fooSet.add(foo);
    }
}
```

The relevant JSON is:

```
{

    "foo": [424082239],

}
```

And the line

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObj, MyBean.class);
```

throws the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.json.JSONException: Error while setting property=foo type interface java.util.List
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.toArray(JSONArray.java:311)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.convertPropertyValueToArray(JSONObject.java:1215)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.toBean(JSONObject.java:353)
    ... 5 more
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious..

Answer (score 0):

I think it expects that your `foo setter` accepts `java.util.List` as a parameter.

Comment: No, when I had that, it didn't think there was a setter there at all.  It was changing the argument to an array that made it work for analogous members that were String based.

Comment: hmmm can you try changing Long to prmitive long ?

Comment: I did, and it gave the 'INFO: property 'foo' of class myBean has no write method.  SKIPPED.' error.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't look at your getters / setters, but using reflection sees your properties - could you try changing `fooSet` to `foo` ?

Comment: Oddly, what worked was leaving the properties alone and creating a dummy setter that takes an array of strings, and parsing the longs from the strings inside the setter (I have some control over the JSON, so I was able to set them as strings instead of longs).